# Scan a subnet for an application that is NOT installed

Tags: powershell, vbscript

I have been trying to come up with a script that will scan a specific subnet for an application not having been installed yet.  I need to see if Lync is installed on some remote subnets before we turn up the sites live next month.

I have been running this as a logon script but it doesn't tell me what subnet they are in and it's not populating fast enough as users don't logoff.

```vb
On Error Resume Next
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
set objSysInfo = CreateObject("ADSystemInfo")
Set objNetwork = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Network")

strValue = objShell.RegRead("HKCU\Software\MRC Custom\Skype_Audit")
If strValue <> "Gathered 1.0" Then
    objShell.RegWrite "HKCU\Software\MRC Custom\Skype_Audit", "Gathered 1.0"

    x86 = objShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%PROGRAMFILES(x86)%")
    skypePath = x86 & "\Microsoft Office\Office15\lync.exe"

    If objFSO.FileExists(skypePath) Then
        version = objFSO.GetFileVersion(skypePath)
    Else
        version = "not installed"
    End If

    'Bind to the users DN
    strUserPath = "LDAP://" & objSysInfo.UserName
    set objUser = GetObject(strUserPath)

    strComputer = "."
    Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")

    'Write Data to Log File
    Const ForAppending = 8
    strPath = "\\mcjunkinredman\data\userpub\Skype_Audit\Log.txt"
    Set objTextFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strPath, ForAppending, True)
    objTextFile.WriteLine objUser.samAccountName & "|" & objNetwork.ComputerName & "|" & version
End If
```

VBScript or PowerShell is fine, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote an article a while back that provides a script that connects to remote computers and retrieves the applications that are installed:

[Windows IT Pro: Auditing 32-Bit and 64-Bit Applications with PowerShell](http://windowsitpro.com/scripting/auditing-32-bit-and-64-bit-applications-powershell)